# Performance difference in simulator and device in my game. Why?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios-simulator, cocos2d-iphone

I am writing a small shooting game using cocos2d. It's working good in simulator. 
But when testing in the device, the animations of sprites are slow and they are stucking.  The images I used are CCSprites. And I used CCAnimation for the animation of the images. Why the game acting different in simulator and device ?

Thank you.

Comment: Because the simulator is running on a > 2 GHz CPU with > 1 GB of RAM and probably a very fast graphics card too.

Comment: Thank You KannyTM.
But, how can I can I make it make it work in device smoothly. Should I change my code for this ? Should I decrease the size of images or speed of animation or any thing else. 

Please give me some direction where I can find about this ?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to find a slower computer to run the simulator on.

Comment: So, that the simulator and device match their speeds and I can check them correctly ? Do, you mean the  same thing ? I will try it. 
Thank you Pete.

Comment: Is that depend on the frame rate. I mean fps 60/60 or 1.0/60. I simulator 60/60 is not working correctly. I mean all images are not displayed in animation. But, when I keep the fps rate as 1.0/60 all images are appearing in smooth animation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must test your application on device always to avoid such problems. Applications in simulator are far better in performance than in device, so it is better to test your crucial application functionalities in device always.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if you are using CCLog - this leads to huge performance drops on the device due to the need to communicate back and forth with the Xcode console.

Comment: I am not using CCLog in my code. I think the problem is with the images I am using. They size is big. I re saved them so that their size decreased by very large amount. So, the performance was now better than before. But, still I need to get the desired speed of animation. I am thinking of using CCSpriteSheet instead of CCSprite. I am following this blog. I think it's good. http://getsetgames.com/2010/04/18/how-to-animate-sprites-in-cocos2d/  

Thank you.